# Create fake flash drive programmatically

Tags: windows, macos, usb-flash-drive

I want to create a fake flash drive programmatically under Mac OSX and Windows. 
It should behave like a normal drive, that means it should appear in explorer/finder, should be unmountable,.. If someone puts some data in it, it should be handled in a backend software.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about a RAM Drive?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing cross-platform frameworks.  For Windows, the documentation for writing device drivers is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557573%28v=VS.85%29.aspx See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463062 but note that this is hard-core stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not aware of any existing cross-platform frameworks. For Windows, the documentation for writing device drivers is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557573. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463062 but note that this is hard-core stuff.